# Is there a possibility to use Apache ActiveMQ/Camel for eDelivery AS4 (EPREL)

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have to implement energy label data transfer to EU (EPREL).
We already Use an Apache ActiveMQ/Camel on Server.
Is there a possibility to use MQ for communicate via [eDelivery AS4](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/wiki/display/CEFDIGITAL/eDelivery+AS4+-+1.15)?

Answer (score 0):

No. Neither ActiveMQ nor Camel support AS4.